# Application crash 1 time out of 3 at start up

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash

Here you can see the stack trace :

```
02-28 11:06:59.285 7460-7460/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-28 11:06:59.357 7460-7460/ I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
02-28 11:06:59.357 7460-7460/ I/MultiDex: install
02-28 11:06:59.357 7460-7460/ I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
02-28 11:06:59.364 7460-7460/ I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
02-28 11:06:59.392 7460-7471/ I/art: humin current process: 
02-28 11:06:59.392 7460-7471/ I/art: current process_level is : 0
02-28 11:06:59.427 7460-7460/ I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.8.97
02-28 11:06:59.463 7460-7471/ I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 26 MB
02-28 11:06:59.472 7460-7499/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:06:59.514 7460-7521/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:06:59.575 7460-7499/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:06:59.583 7460-7460/ A/Adjust: SANDBOX: Adjust is running in Sandbox mode. Use this setting for testing. Don't forget to set the environment to `production` before publishing!
02-28 11:06:59.600 7460-7460/ I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
02-28 11:06:59.616 7460-7521/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:06:59.711 7460-7471/ I/art: current process_level is : 0
02-28 11:07:00.136 7460-7460/ I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-28 11:07:00.181 7460-7581/ W/linker: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libgmscore.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libgmscore.so"
02-28 11:07:00.201 7460-7523/ I/Adjust: Google Play Services Advertising ID read correctly at start time
02-28 11:07:00.204 7460-7581/ W/linker: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x80
02-28 11:07:00.204 7460-7581/ W/linker: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so"
02-28 11:07:00.226 7460-7581/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl>
02-28 11:07:00.226 7460-7581/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl>
02-28 11:07:00.243 7460-7581/ I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
02-28 11:07:00.453 7460-7471/ I/art: current process_level is : 0
02-28 11:07:00.465 7460-7460/ I/RatingManager: Launch Time was increase =>4
02-28 11:07:00.502 7460-7460/ W/MixpanelAPI.ConfigurationChecker: com.mixpanel.android.surveys.SurveyActivity is not registered as an activity in your application, so surveys can't be shown.
02-28 11:07:00.504 7460-7628/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:07:00.546 7460-7628/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:07:00.571 7460-7460/ I/GAv4: Google Analytics 9.4.52 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                                    adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                                    adb logcat -s GAv4
02-28 11:07:00.578 7460-7460/ I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustAlarmManagerImpl
02-28 11:07:00.581 7460-7460/ I/GAv4: Logger is deprecated. To enable debug logging, please run:
                                                  adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
02-28 11:07:00.581 7460-7632/ W/GAv4: AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices.
02-28 11:07:00.583 7460-7632/ W/GAv4: CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible.
02-28 11:07:00.586 7460-7632/ W/GAv4: AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably.
02-28 11:07:00.596 7460-7460/ E/MyEquipmentsFragment: onResume()
02-28 11:07:00.659 7460-7471/ I/art: current process_level is : 0
02-28 11:07:00.728 7460-7460/ I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 56.0.2924.87 (code 292408750)
02-28 11:07:00.775 7460-7460/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
02-28 11:07:00.775 7460-7460/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
02-28 11:07:00.780 7460-7460/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
02-28 11:07:00.781 7460-7460/ I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
02-28 11:07:00.786 7460-7460/ I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 7898-7899)
02-28 11:07:00.786 7460-7460/ I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "56.0.2924.87", actual native library version number "56.0.2924.87"
02-28 11:07:00.795 7460-7460/ I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "56.0.2924.87", actual native library version number "56.0.2924.87"
02-28 11:07:00.795 7460-7460/ I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-28 11:07:00.808 7460-7460/ I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
02-28 11:07:00.946 7460-7460/ I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is enabled.
02-28 11:07:00.987 7460-7681/ E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.022 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
02-28 11:07:01.023 7460-7681/ I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
02-28 11:07:01.024 7460-7681/ I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
02-28 11:07:01.027 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-pn-realvideo
02-28 11:07:01.029 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg
02-28 11:07:01.030 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
02-28 11:07:01.030 7460-7681/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized ·460-7681/ I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
02-28 11:07:01.096 7460-7460/ W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.FrameLayout{2d4818c V.E...... ......ID 0,312-1080,1572 #7f0e017e app:id/fragment_scan_fl_container_scan} during layout: running second layout pass
02-28 11:07:01.106 7460-7460/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-28 11:07:01.309 7460-7513/ I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
02-28 11:07:01.317 7460-7460/ I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7460 SIG: 9
```

---

Do you have any idea what can it be the origin of those crashes ?

Comment: Are you sure this log contains any crash info?

Comment: It's the only log I get, I don't see any error/exceptions that's why i'm confused

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

overide following method in your application class.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: What are those line doing more than the gradle dependancy with dex enabled "true" ?

Comment: @An-droid you can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a real explication instead of a link. I've tried your answer but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

log suggests that some of the native .so's (libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so and libgmscore.so) with your app have been linked with SONAME turned off. This leaved the ELF's embedded DT_SONAME entry in these .so's, empty. With earlier android versions, if that was the case (i.e. missing DT_SONAME in the ELF) then the loader would look for the raw file name in-order to satisfy the dependency; and it used to work. However with recent Android versions, that no longer is the case I guess, and the embedded DT_SONAME of the dependency should match the "NEEDED" .so name in the dependent.